# Stop criterion on objective function (IPOPT)

Tags: python-2.7, openmdao, ipopt

Here is my problem : I am optimizing different problems with openmdao using different solvers.
A problem gives me an objective function that has 1 or more roots, and my goal is to get close to one using optimization.
There is no problem with SLSQP or PSQP for instance, but when using IPOPT, here is what i can get from printing detailed results (extract):
[image]

My problem might be badly scaled or something, but is there a way to make IPOPT stop when the objective function is (for instance) lower than 1e-5 ?
I need to fix 'tol' around 5. to get what i want in this particular problem, but 'tol' influences on Eo which does not only depend on the objective function ... Anyone has an idea ?
thanks by advance

Answer (score 0):

Ipopt has a bunch of different convergence tolerances. Check out some documentation at: http://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node42.html

Setting that up properly will get it to stop when you would like. You might want to try `acceptable_tol`, it looks for when the answer stops changing as a termination criterion.

Comment: I already checked that link. I have to set a high 'dual_inf_tol' to make my problem stop early (inf_du is about 1e1). Thing is the tol and acceptable_tol criterions depend on many sub variable of the problem according to the implementation paper (http://cepac.cheme.cmu.edu/pasilectures/biegler/ipopt.pdf).
So there is apparently no pre determined value i could set to make it stop when the objective function is under a value. Hence my question about a way to do it (that would not be specified in the termination section of the documentation)

Comment: it sounds like you're not happy with their built in stopping criterion. You could modify the OpenMDAO wrapper code to add your own stopping criterion. You'll need to be a little careful for it not to turn out as a total hack, but if you just need something quick and dirty then hack away: https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/master/openmdao/drivers/pyoptsparse_driver.py#L423

Comment: It is exactly what it sounds like. It seems that _objfunc is only used for the Optimization class (from pyoptsparse). I don't see any way to change the stopping criterions from the wrapper, as the wrapper directly calls the optimizer and only treats the results... And changing the code of IPOPT seems to be way too difficult :/